# Why my byte array is split at 0x00 when i insert it into my db (SQL SERVER, C++)

Tags: c++, sql-server-2008, arrays, odbc, varbinarymax

I have to insert a byte array into a VARBINARY(max) in SQLServer2008 trough a stored procedure and when one of my byte array element is equal to 0x00 my byte array is split.

I use an SQLBindParameter to insert my data in the DB, and it work normally when I haven't any 0x00 value in my array.

Comment: Would you happen to be using a `std::string` to store binary data ? And remember to always show some code !

Comment: Nop i have to use a regular byte array `byte var[]` and it's probably not a code problem.
But that my bind : `SQLBindParameter(m_hSQLStmt,4,SQL_PARAM_INPUT,SQL_C_BINARY,SQL_LONGVARBINARY,iSizeOfData*sizeof(baData),NULL,baData,NULL,NULL);`

Comment: Could the byte array perchance be treated as a `char[]` or `char*` at some point?

Comment: Yep in the bind `baData` is a byte * which designe my array

Answer (score 0):

I can also change my insertion method, so if somebody already done something to put a binary stream (byte[]) in an varbinary in sql server it will probably really help me.